# Getting AppContainer SID

Tags: c++, windows, sid, appcontainer

I'm trying to open the directory object within a AppContainer object:

```
\\Sessions\\<Session#>\\AppContainerNamedObjects\\<AppContainer-SID>
```

I can't seem to get the value <AppContainer-SID> within the process.

This value is visible using Process Explorer

[image: Value in Process Explorer]
I didn't find a way to get it using the code. Is there any way to get this value on process start?

Comment: `OpenProcess+OpenProcessToken+GetTokenInformation` with `TokenAppContainerSid`